# Problemas de seguridad en sistema Web

Tags: php, mysql, validación, seguridad, permisos

Saludos, expongo mi caso:

Actualmente, en mi sistema, para poder trabajar los usuarios inician sesion y ellos ven las opciones que corresponden de acuerdo a su perfil de usuario, el problema es que yo solo valido si el usuario ha iniciado sesión, pero no valido si el archivo que el usuario tiene abierto es el que corresponde ver, por lo que, ya que existe ese vacío en mi sistema, los usuarios realizan la mala práctica de copiar la URL de un archivo del sistema (que solo los usuarios con perfil "X" pueden ver) y la pegan en la barra de direcciones y ya trabajan en un área que no deberían.

Cabe mencionar que, actualmente, los perfiles de usuario me ocultan las opciones de menú que no deberían ver los usuarios, pero si los usuarios copian y pegan la URL podrán entrar

**¿Cómo puedo evitar eso?**

***Opción1:***
Yo no tengo ningún problema en colocar un indicativo a cada archivo del sistema y almacenar en la base de datos el listado de archivos que puede ver cada usuario, pero veo que es demasiado trabajo puesto que mi sistema posee aproximadamente 1500 usuarios y casi la misma cantidad de archivos (archivos de interfaz).

***Opción2***
Otra opción que no tengo problema de implementa (y la que más tengo ganas de implementar) es que puedo almacenar en la tabla de perfiles de usuario, los indicativos que los archivos en el sistema, luego, en la interfaz de usuario validar que el perfil del usuario tiene abierto el archivo con un indicativo especifico, ejemplo:

formulario1.php (posee una costante con un valor)

```
validar_perfil($idusuario,$idperfil,VALOR_CONSTANTE);
//Esta funcion me validaría si el archivo identificado con el valor de CONSTANTE está dentro del catalogo de perfiles.
```

Básicamente las opciones son las mismas lo que cambia es que la opción 1 comparo indicativo de archivo versus catalogo que cada usuario puede ver y la segunda comparo indicativo de archivo versus perfil que tiene acceso a ese archivo.

**¿Cuál es la mejor forma? ¿Me estoy complicando la vida? ¿Hay más propuestas que puedan ofrecerme?**

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: Pues te sugiero que más que amarrarlo a un usuario lo amarres a un puesto donde definas a que interfaces se tiene acceso cada puesto o perfil, y que en cuanto entre a una interfaz que no le corresponde le bloquees la pagina hasta puedes mandarle un mensaje de advertencia donde digas que esta tratando de accesar una pagina a la cual no esta autorizado.

Comment: Hola djcandido, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Antes que nada te invito a que conozcas esta comunidad visitando el [tour]. Ahora te  comento que este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas a opiniones no son permitidas en el sitio (más info [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). En resumen, se prefiere un [mcve] del problema a preguntas hipotéticas.

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Yo tengo un problema parecido, que he [planteado también hoy](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65017/29967) Actualmente tengo protegidas las carpetas a través de `.htaccess`. Ningún usuario puede entrar a **nada** de esa carpeta sin contraseña. Claro, eso no sirve si en una misma carpeta tienes que tener por obligación archivos para varios niveles de usuario.

Comment: Lo más común es implementar un sistema de roles o permisos, hay varias formas de hacer. Todo depende de cuantos roles necesites si es solo 2, por ejemplo usuario y admin, añades un campo a la tabla usuarios en el que almacenará el tipo de usuario, 1 para admin 2 para usuarios. Luego al crear la sesión guardas este va los el la sesión y en cada una de las páginas válidas si el rol tiene permiso o no. Para darte una respuesta más precisa necesitaría saber los requerimientos de forma más específica.