# Evitar que un archivo PHP sea llamado directamente desde el navegador

Tags: php

He intentado muchos métodos, pero a la final siempre fallan.
El único que no me dio problemas fue hacer una validación con `GET` obteniendo el `id`,

```
if(!isset($_GET[id])){
{ 
 header('Location: /App'); }
}
```

pero da igual por que cualquiera puede acceder con solo poner `link.com/ruta/?id=cualquiercosa`

Comment: Necesito más datos. Es un archivo de inclusión que no quieres que pueda ser visitado? Es un script php de consola? No quieres que nadie pueda visitarlo salvo tú?

Comment: ¿Solucionaste el problema? ¿Alguna respuesta te aclaró tu duda? Si es así te agradecería que marcaras como correcta aquella que consideres. Gracias.

Answer (score 6):

Las formas más seguras de evitar que ejecuten tus scripts PHP de forma directa son:

**Alojándolos fuera de la raíz del sitio web (*document root*)**

Tu sitio web debería tener una estructura similar a ésta:

```
/var/html/
├── html_publico/
│   ├── imagenes/
│   ├── css/
│   └── index.php
└── aplicacion/
    ├── script_php1.php
    └── script_php2.php
```

Es la práctica más recomendada y es la que usan la mayoría de frameworks (Slim, Symfony, etc).

Puedes ver un ejemplo en la [documentación de Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/2011/09/24/how-to-organize-a-large-slim-framework-application.html) y otro en la [documentación de Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html).

**Usando definición de variables**

Cuando la solución anterior no se puede usar (nuestro alojamiento no nos permite acceder a un nivel superior de nuestro sitio web) podemos adoptar esta solución alternativa, aunque es menos recomendable y puede llevar a error por olvidar la comprobación en algún archivo.

Si un script PHP puede ser accedido directamente en su primera línea se define una constante usando [`define()`](http://php.net/define):

```
define('ACCESO_PERMITIDO', true);
```

Si no se permite el acceso directo a él lo que se hace es comprobar que haya sido definida la constante a través de un script permitido haciendo uso de [`defined()`](http://php.net/defined):

```
if (defined('ACCESO_PERMITIDO') === false) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit();
}
```

**Denegando el acceso en el servidor HTTP**

Otra alternativa que podríamos usar es configurar el servidor web para rechazar el acceso a un directorio donde almacenemos los scripts PHP protegidos.

Es una práctica desaconsejada porque al migrar de un servidor a otro podría cambiar algún parámetro (como el `AllowOverride` de Apache) que permitiera el acceso a los archivos que pensábamos que estaban protegidos.

En Apache se hace uso de [los controles de acceso](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) en un bloque `<Directory>` o un archivo `.htaccess`.

Si usamos la solución del archivo `.htaccess` nuestra estructura de directorios podría ser la siguiente:

```
/var/html/
├── scripts/
│   ├── .htaccess
│   ├── script_php1.php
│   └── script_php2.php
├── imagenes/
├── css/
└── index.php
```

Un contenido de `.htaccess` que impediría el acceso directo a cualquier archivo de su interior sería:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
```

Debemos recordar que para usar un archivo `.htaccess` la directiva [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride) debería permitir el uso de su contenido mediante la directiva [`Limit`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) en la configuración del sitio web:

```
<Directory /var/html/scripts>
  AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

Ya que estamos en el uso del bloque `<Directory>` en la configuración del sitio web ésta podría ser, sin necesitar `.htaccess` ni permitir `Limit` con `AllowOverride`:

```
<Directory /var/html/scripts>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Y en un servidor NGINX se configuraría el sitio web de la siguiente manera (usando rutas relativas de la URL, no rutas de directorios locales):

```
location /scripts {
  deny all;
  return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que nadie pueda ingresar al archivo, no lo dejs público. Si tu sitio vive en `/var/www/html` entonces puedes poner los archivos en `/var/archivos`.

Ahora, no puedes evitar que la gente fabrique sus propios requests, dicho esto tu mejor opción para asegurar tus archivos es obscurenciendolos.

[Aquí he dado una respuesta sobre como servir archivos protegidos.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/73249/23327)

[Aquí es la respuesta original que contiene el mecanismo que puedes usar para servir cualquier tipo de archivos.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/68359/23327)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Tomado de codeigniter. Te puede servir esa función para validarlo, colocalo justo encima de tu archivo php y verifica si te sirve.

En mi caso lo uso para cada controlador en caso que quieran acceder colocando el nombre del archivo directamente.